# Reading linked files

Tags: java

I have written a java app for a makefile. The app crawls through the files in a folder and read them one by one to get the include files. But it doesnot reports all the files. The app is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class testCrawler {

/**
 * @param args
 */

static String path = "C:\\APP_Eclipse\\TestCrawler\\Test";
static Scanner sc;
static FileReader fr;
static BufferedReader br;
static FileWriter fw;
static BufferedWriter bw;
static String make = "makefile";
static String line;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File f = new File(path);
    folderCrawler(f);
}

static public void folderCrawler(File f) throws IOException{
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    String name;
    String[] names;

    fw = new FileWriter(make);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for(File aFile:files){
        name = aFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        names = name.split("\\.");
        bw.write(names[0] + ".o : " + name);
        if ((name.endsWith(".c") || (name.endsWith(".h")))){
            try{
                fr = new FileReader(path + "\\" + name);
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path +     "\\"      + name));
                while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
                    line = line.trim();
                    if (line.contains("#include") &&    line.contains("\"")){
                        line = line.replace("#include", "");
                        line = line.replace("\"", "");
                        line = line.trim();
                        System.out.println("LINE : " + line);
                        bw.write(" " + line + " ");
                        makeMakefile(line);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            bw.write("\n");
        }
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
}

static public void makeMakefile(String name) throws Exception{

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "\\" + name));
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
        if (line.contains("#include") && line.contains("\"")){
            line = line.replace("#include", "");
            line = line.replace("\"", "");
            line = line.trim();
            System.out.println("LINE : " + line);
        bw.write(" " + line + " ");
            makeMakefile(line);
        }
    }       
}

}
```

The files that are read:
test.c containing :

```
#include "test.h"
#include "test_1.h"
```

Test.h containing :

```
#include "test_2.h"
#include "test_3.h"
```

and the files test_1.h, test_2.h and test_3.h (these files contain nothing).

The make file should be :

```
test.o : test.c test.h test_1.h
test.o : test.h test_2.h test_3.h
test_1.o : test_1.h
test_2.o : test_2.h
test_3.o : test_3.h
```

But is :

```
test.o : test.c test.h
test.o : test.h test_2.h
test_1.o : test_1.h
test_2.o : test_2.h
test_3.o : test_3.h
```

I know where the error comes from : line=br.readLine() become null when return from makeMakefile and I can not read the net line in file.

How can to avoid this ?

Thanks a lot

EB

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining your `BufferedReader` when you call `makeMakeFile()`, and you're passing the line read from your C file, as opposed to the filename.  So, it will always work when you only have one `#include`, but it won't work after that, because `br` now points to a file cooresponding to the line from your C code, which probably doesn't exist, but you're throwing a `FileNotFoundException` and handling it in your main.

Additionally, why are you calling the code in your main and immediately afterwards in a another function?

Comment: I understand, But how can I point to the new file in which to read ?

Comment: @EB You're already doing that in your `try`.  Also, `fr` is not required in your code, as it does nothing.  You're creating a `FileReader` in your `BufferedReader` constructor.  Using methods is good, but the way you call your method doesn't make sense.  Your method has no reason for being recursive, and it doesn't make sense to use your current main and call the exact same code snippet again, albeit incorrectly.

Comment: P Thank you. I use recursivity because is the same flow of operation i.e.: read a file - write its naem, if it has include's files open first, read it - write the name and so om. It ends when there are only when it encounters system files enclosed between <>. I honestly don't see any other way. But, perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @EB I don't understand.  You're looping through all of you files in a selected folder, then for each file with a certain extension, you're looping through the lines to include the proper things in your makefile.  Why do you need recursion here?  What you're actually doing is looping through all of the files in a folder, once you find a file of interest, you read one line, call the same code that just executed on a file that doesn't exist.  You can just call the while loop once per file, write whatever you need, and then go to the next file.

Comment: I did not make my self clear. I loop through the files;I open the file; I look for the files I am interested; if I find one, I open it; I look for the files and so on.

Comment: Meanwhile I used the following trick: every time I open a fle, I open a new BufferedReader; when I exit the file I close it. And it worked for me.

Comment: Thank for your tips;It gave me ideas.

Comment: @EB Yeah, I'd probably do something like that.  Glad it worked out.  Even so, you should try to clean up your code a little bit.  It was kinda messy and unnecessarily repetitious.  Good luck!